# ARM watchdog reset

Tags: arm, watchdog

I have an MP3 development board I picked up from sparkfun that runs off the LPC2148 ARM processor. In looking through the code, I see a function to force a watchdog reset. My question is, how do you figure out what values to feed to the watchdog register? I looked through the LPC2148 data sheet and couldn't figure it out. I don't just want to use other people's code, I want to understand why they did what they did and how they figured out what to do.

Answer (score 5):

This is the code I use for an LPC2148:

WDTC = 0x00000FFF;  // very short timeout

WDMOD = 0x03;       // watchdog resets CPU

WDFEED = 0xAA;      // start watchdog

WDFEED = 0x55;

Comment: 0xAA and 0x55 are often used in this sort of code which affects an application in a big way, as they are unlikely to be encountered during normal code execution. - Leon Heller

Answer (score 4):

From the LPC23XX datasheet, should be the same for LPC2148 ::

> Watchdog feed sequence register.
>   Writing 0xAA  followed by 0x55 to this
>   register reloads the  Watchdog timer
>   with the value contained in  WDTC.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to force a watchdog reset, not keep the watchdog from resetting you.  This is accomplished by a misfeed: feeding the watchdog 0xaa followed by a value OTHER than 0x55.  Example:

```
WDFEED = 0xAA;    /* Correct feed... */
WDFEED = 0x00;    /* ... Oops, insta-reset! */
```